# Проблема с $(window).scroll(function ()

Tags: jquery

Есть скрипт на сайте:

```
var header = $('.header__hamburger'),
        scrollPrev = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    if ( scrolled > 100 && scrolled > scrollPrev+200 ) {
        $('.header__hamburger').fadeOut();
    } else {
        $('.header__hamburger').fadeIn();
    }
    scrollPrev = scrolled;
});
```

Он скрывает или показывает гамбургер при прокрутке. И на десктопе все норм а на телефоне гамбургер моргает при скрытии. Такое ощущение что $('.header__hamburger').fadeOut() вызывается много раз.
Подскажите пожалуйста куда копать.

Comment: Не знаю как в браузере на телефоне ведёт себя событие scroll, но в приложении, например, за время проведения пальцем по экрану этих событий генерируется большое количество. Если здесь так же, то, например, десяток-сотня `fadeIn`-ов (ведь `scrolled` отличается от `scrollPrev` на 1-2, а не на 200) могут испортить `fadeOut`

Comment: Кажется, что в if-e должно быть другое условие, а else, который вызывается во **всех** остальных случаях, отсутствовать вовсе (вместо него, например, может быть второй if)

Comment: Ну то что в тач устройствах все не так я понял. Но не понял что делать) Я начинающий разработчик. Прошел курсы, сделал сайт. И вот при адаптации столкнулся с ворохом проблем.Я не понимаю что за другое условие должно быть....

Comment: Тут вопрос в логике: как и что должно работать. Для этого нужно понять (а лучше расписать) все случаи. После чего можно будет уже код писать. Лично я по коду и тексту не смог понять в чем задумка (например: зачем `+200`, почему именно 200, зачем вообще `scrollPrev`), поэтому просто взять и поправить код не могу

Comment: +200 это случайность) Логика- из любого места страницы при листании в одном направлении скрывать элемент сайта(в этом примере гамбургер) а в другом его наоборот показывать

Answer (score 0):

Хм, у меня ваш код не работает даже на ПК, у вас в if какое-то совершенно не понятное условие, также в данном коде не понятно зачем вообще у вас есть scrollPrev.

Могу предложить такой вариант

```
var header = $('.header__hamburger');
let trig = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    if ( scrolled > 100) {
        if(!trig){
            $('.header__hamburger').fadeOut();
            trig = true;
        }
    } else {
        $('.header__hamburger').fadeIn();
        trig = false;

    }
});
```

Здесь еще добавлена проверка на срабатывание условия при скролле > 100. В таком варианте .fadeOut будет вызываться единожды

Comment: +200 лишнее в моем коде это следы экспериментов.))Код работает и скрывает или показывает гамбургер при скроллинге их любого места экрана но гамбургер моргает.При вашем  варианте гамбургер появляется только если долистать вверх. А задача его показать их любого места сайта при скроллинге вверх

Answer (score 0):

Если необходимо скрывать при скролле вниз и показывать при скролле вверх можете использовать этот код

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var mainHeader = $('.cd-auto-hide-header'),
    secondaryNavigation = $('.cd-secondary-nav'),
    //this applies only if secondary nav is below intro section
    belowNavHeroContent = $('.sub-nav-hero'),
    headerHeight = mainHeader.height();

  //set scrolling variables
  var scrolling = false,
    previousTop = 0,
    currentTop = 0,
    scrollDelta = 5,
    scrollOffset = 150; // Указыватеся на сколько должна быть проскроленна страница перед скрытием header

  mainHeader.on('click', '.nav-trigger', function(event) {
    // open primary navigation on mobile
    event.preventDefault();
    mainHeader.toggleClass('nav-open');
  });

  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if (!scrolling) {
      scrolling = true;
      (!window.requestAnimationFrame) ?
      setTimeout(autoHideHeader, 250): requestAnimationFrame(autoHideHeader);
    }
  });

  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    headerHeight = mainHeader.height();
  });

  function autoHideHeader() {
    var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    (belowNavHeroContent.length > 0) ?
    checkStickyNavigation(currentTop) // secondary navigation below intro
      : checkSimpleNavigation(currentTop);

    previousTop = currentTop;
    scrolling = false;
  }

  function checkSimpleNavigation(currentTop) {
    //there's no secondary nav or secondary nav is below primary nav
    if (previousTop - currentTop > scrollDelta) {
      //if scrolling up...
      mainHeader.removeClass('is-hidden');
    } else if (currentTop - previousTop > scrollDelta && currentTop > scrollOffset) {
      //if scrolling down...
      if (mainHeader.hasClass('onHover')) {
        console.log('test')
      } else {
        mainHeader.addClass('is-hidden');
      }

    }
  }

  function checkStickyNavigation(currentTop) {
    //secondary nav below intro section - sticky secondary nav
    var secondaryNavOffsetTop = belowNavHeroContent.offset().top - secondaryNavigation.height() - mainHeader.height();

    if (previousTop >= currentTop) {
      //if scrolling up... 
      if (currentTop < secondaryNavOffsetTop) {
        //secondary nav is not fixed
        mainHeader.removeClass('is-hidden');
        secondaryNavigation.removeClass('fixed slide-up');
        belowNavHeroContent.removeClass('secondary-nav-fixed');
      } else if (previousTop - currentTop > scrollDelta) {
        //secondary nav is fixed
        mainHeader.removeClass('is-hidden');
        secondaryNavigation.removeClass('slide-up').addClass('fixed');
        belowNavHeroContent.addClass('secondary-nav-fixed');
      }

    } else {
      //if scrolling down... 
      if (currentTop > secondaryNavOffsetTop + scrollOffset) {
        //hide primary nav
        mainHeader.addClass('is-hidden');
        secondaryNavigation.addClass('fixed slide-up');
        belowNavHeroContent.addClass('secondary-nav-fixed');
      } else if (currentTop > secondaryNavOffsetTop) {
        //once the secondary nav is fixed, do not hide primary nav if you haven't scrolled more than scrollOffset 
        mainHeader.removeClass('is-hidden');
        secondaryNavigation.addClass('fixed').removeClass('slide-up');
        belowNavHeroContent.addClass('secondary-nav-fixed');
      }

    }
  }
});
```

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 80px;
  background: #000;
  z-index: 101;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.header.is-hidden {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header cd-auto-hide-header"></header>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```